# Use SMF session data for the rest of the website

Tags: php, session-variables

I am trying to implement SMF to handle accounts for my website, and I need to figure out how to reach the user id in the session in order for me to merge my forums into the site.

It's the only value needed to merge the two, but I can't figure out if the SMF user id is in the session data, yet alone what they may have named it.

I tried adding this to SSI.php to find it, but not even the 3333's were showing.

```
echo "<tr><td>";
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    echo $key." ".$val;
echo "</td><td>33333333333333333333333333333333333</td></tr>";
```

Comment: View source in browser. You find anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for some better debug output:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$buffer = ob_get_clean();

echo '<tr><td><pre>', htmlspecialchars($buffer), '</pre></td></tr>';
```

Alternatively also look into the browsers source-code.

Comment: Somehow, deleting the contents of SSI.php and uploading it as an empty file does not affect the site. Probably why I can't debug it for an answer.